# How to partially redact a string

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to partially redact strings in a list.

I have a list like this:

```
list = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'duckduckgo.com']
```

and I would like this list to end up like this

```
redacted_list = ['**ogl*.com', 'b**g.com', '*u*kd***go.com']
```

I have looked at using the function random.choices() but can't figure out how to replace the choices with asterixis. Any advice on how to go about this would be useful, all I can find is information on fully redacting words nothing about partial redactions for say 50% of the characters in a string.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
import random
result = []
for i in l1:
    i,suffix = i.rsplit('.') 
    temp = [k for k in i]
    for j in random.sample(range(len(i) - 1),len(i)//2):
        temp[j] = '*'
    result.append(''.join(temp) + '.' + suffix)

print(result) # ['**o*le.com', '*i*g.com', '*u**d*ckg.com']
```

Comment: `NameError: name "l1" is undefined` …

Comment: l1 = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'duckduckgo.com'] I've used l1 as the name of initial string

Comment: And I think the OP wants only the domain name to be asterixed, not the dot nor the `.com`

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
import random

def convert(inlist):
    outlist = []
    for domain in inlist:
        domain, tld = domain.split(".") # google.com : domain contains google and tld contains com
        domain = list(domain) # need to convert str to list - domain[i] = "*" will fail if we dont
        to_replace = random.choices(range(len(domain)), k=random.randint(0, len(domain))) # pick which letters of the domain name to replace
        for i in to_replace:
            domain[i] = "*"
        outlist.append("".join(domain) + "." + tld) # put g*o*l* and com back together and append the result to the output
    return outlist

inlist = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'duckduckgo.com']

for indomain, outdomain in zip(inlist, convert(inlist)):
    print("%s became %s" % (indomain, outdomain))
```

Sample output:

```py
google.com became g*og*e.com
bing.com became bin*.com
duckduckgo.com became d*c*d**k**.com
```

Comment: also if u want to partially redact and just have the first and last 4 chars showing, you could do something like this: `print('{}{}{}'.format(word[:4],'X'*(len(word)-8),word[:4]))`

Answer (score -1):

try this

```py
import random

res = []

names = ['google.com', 'bing.com', 'duckduckgo.com']


for name in names:
    new_url = ""
    domain, p = name.split('.')[0], name.split('.')[-1]
    length = len(domain)
    random_char_indexes = set([random.randint(1, length) for i in range(length)])
    for index, char in enumerate(domain):
        if index in random_char_indexes:
            new_url += "*"
        else:
            new_url += char
    new_url += "."+p
    res.append(new_url)

print(res)
```

Comment: Okay, your code works … But one can see on the second view that you are not learning Python for long ! ;)